# Is this a reliable add edit delete VB codes?

Tags: vb.net, forms, registration

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim condi As Integer
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Password = 12345 ; User ID = sa ; Initial Catalog=log_In ; Data Source= DELL-PC")

'ADD 
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    con.Open()
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save changes?", vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        If condi = 1 Then
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert Into emp (empName,empUserName,empPass) Values (@empName,@empUser,@empPass)", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empName", txtName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empUser", txtUser.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empPass", txtPass.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Record successfully added.")
        ElseIf MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save changes?", vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.No Then
            con.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

'EDIT
Private Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    con.Open()
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save changes?", vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("update emp set empName = @empName, empUserName = @empUser ,empPass = @empPass where empName = @empName ", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empName", txtName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empUser", txtUser.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empPass", txtPass.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Record successfully updated.")
    ElseIf MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save changes?", vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        con.Close()
    End If
End Sub

'DELETE
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    con.Open()
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("delete from emp where empName = @empName", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empName", txtName.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Record successfully deleted!.")
    ElseIf MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        con.Close()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Hi im still a student and this code is just a source from my classmates code. We're doing a system and I have chosen a monitoring and profiling system which is very easy for programmers. Sad to say, I'm not into programming. I can't even start from scratch doing. But still I want to learn. So please tell me where did this code gone wrong. 
Please tell me if I violate some forum decorum / rules. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

this is good... you parameter our inputs and that is what is most important

only one thing to change... 
move your con.close statement out of your else if statement, if not you are not closing your connection!

like so

```
    Private Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click

        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save changes?", vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
con.Open()
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("update emp set empName = @empName, empUserName = @empUser ,empPass = @empPass where empName = @empName ", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empName", txtName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empUser", txtUser.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empPass", txtPass.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Record successfully updated.")
             con.Close() 
        End If

    End Sub

make sure to change all the code...
you may also want to make a single sub and call it... i will write it up in a min...
again what you did is fine but i would use something like


    Public Sub saveChanges(howto As String, txtName As String, txtUser As String, txtPass As String, condi As Integer)
                Dim con As New SqlConnection("Password = 12345 ; User ID = sa ; Initial Catalog=log_In ; Data Source= DELL-PC")
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
                cmd.Connection = con
                Select Case howto
                    Case "add"
                        cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into emp (empName,empUserName,empPass) Values (@empName,@empUser,@empPass)"
                    Case "edit"
                        condi = 1
                        cmd.CommandText = "update emp set empName = @empName, empUserName = @empUser ,empPass = @empPass where empName = @empName "
                    Case "delete"
                        condi = 1
                        cmd.CommandText = "delete from emp where empName = @empName"
                End Select
                'here we write the info
                con.Open()
                If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save changes?", vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                    If condi = 1 Then
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empName", txtName)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empUser", txtUser)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("empPass", txtPass)
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        con.Close()
                        MessageBox.Show("Record successfully added.")
                    End If
                End If
                con.Close()
            End Sub
```

and call it like so

```
call saveChanges ("add",txtName.text,txtUser.txt,txtPass.text,condi)
```

you dont have to worry about condi var outside of the add because i set it to 1 in the select statment

hope this helps! let me know if you need anything else

Comment: @Ishey4- One change I would make it to open the connection inside of the if statement. That way the connection is open for as little time as possible. Currently if a user leaves the message prompt up for whatever reasons, the connection to the database is still open.